# How to migrate List fold to null saftey

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

this code runs fine without null safety:

```
void main() {
  final a = X(22.5);
  final b = X(22.5);
  List<X> x = [a, b];
  var tot = x.fold(0.0, (a, b) => a + b.dist);
  print(tot);
}

class X {
  final double dist;
  X(this.dist);
}
```

with null safety we get:

**The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try adding a null check to the target ('!').**

No idea who/what the target is or the receiver for that matter.  I've read all the Dart material on null safety and can't get this to build as an arrow expression ( => a + b.dist).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pick one of the approaches below:

1. Define the `fold` method type parameter explicitly:

```dart
var tot = x.fold<double>(0.0, (a, b) => a + b.dist);
```

2. Define the `tot` variable type explicitly:

```dart
double tot = x.fold(0.0, (a, b) => a + b.dist);
```